# HTML5 Input Type Time — override default value which is set by delete / backspace keydown event

Tags: html

I am using the input type "time" for selecting a time. When pressing the "delete" or "backspace" button the hour or minutes are set to "--". I want to override this value. When pressing "delete" or "backspace" the default value should be "00". How can i do that?

I am using Google Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131.

```html
<input type="time" name="example">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an event listener, like this?

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (input.value === '') {
        input.value = '00:00';
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="time" name="example">
```

Comment: No i didnt, but with this solution the whole value gets changed. When pressing delete or backspace only the hours or minutes should be changed into "00" instead of "--".

Comment: I think that's the browser intended behaviour. If you console.log the value on backspace, you see that the input value is an empty string.

Comment: youre right, the input value is an empty string... anyway i used this fix now, because its still better than the "--"... thanks!